# .keypress on a DIV tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

Is there a way to get work .keypress on a div element like this?:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

$('#idtext').keypress(function(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  $('#idtext').text(function(i, text) {

   return text + String.fromCharCode(keyCode); 

  });

});

// -->
</script>

<div id="idtext"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes: you need to add a `tabindex` attribute to the `<div>` to allow it to receive the focus.

```
<div id="idtext" tabindex="1"></div>
```

Also, the property you want for the character code of the text entered in a keypress event is `which`, not `keyCode`.

Finally, the HTML comment tags inside the `<script>` element are unnecessary in all modern browsers.

Comment: The example is way too complicated to say that it's my suggestion that's not working. Simplified: http://jsbin.com/aqiza/7

Comment: @xRobot you have mistake change `$('#cmd span');` to `$('#cmd div#mytext');` see http://jsbin.com/aqiza/13

Comment: Many thanks for the `tabindex` trick. I'd never figure it out.