# Why doesn't keydown event work on regular container div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I must be losing it, I can't get the keydown event to work:

I tried:

```
$('#container').keydown(function() {
            console.log("down");
            alert('down');
    });
```

Also tried:

```
$('#container').on('keydown',function() {
            console.log("down");
            alert('down');
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/mwptttdv/

Comment: Because only form elements (almost) are focusable, and only focused elements can detect keyboard events. You can add `tabindex="0"` to the `div` [to gain focus](http://jsfiddle.net/rvL64c7j/) to it.

Comment: ahhh answered same time as me. Add your answer as an answer. Deleting mine.

Comment: @Ted I'm searching for a dup, there must be a one ... [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759339/keypress-on-a-div-tag), and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149362/capture-key-press-or-keydown-event-on-div-element).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually can get the browser to recognize the keydown on the div if you give it a tabindex attribute:

```
<div id='container' tabindex="1"></div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mwptttdv/1/)**

Comment: Clever. Probably worth it to note that the element must be selected.